# How to get newly inserted @rid from OrientDb?

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I have simple function (javascript language)like this.

```
var db = orient.getDatabase();
var result = db.command("Insert into Counter (Name, Value) values('Test1',0)");
```

How can I get New @rid from `result` variable?
I have tried like this

```
return result[0].field('@rid');
```

But it wont worked.

Comment: Could you add some detail on error messages or other observations that made you think it did not work? That is a helpful part of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you case by following these steps:

**Structure:**

```
CREATE CLASS Counter

CREATE PROPERTY Counter.Name STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Counter.Value INTEGER
```

To retrieve the just inserted record **`@rid`** by using a **Javascript function** you can change your function in this way:

**JS function:**

```
var db = orient.getDatabase();

var result = db.command("Insert into Counter (Name, Value) values('Test1',0)");

return result.getRecord().field('@rid').toString();
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "value": "#12:0"
    }
]
```

**Studio:**

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: can i use this `result.getRecord().field('@rid').toString();` for
 `var result2=db.command("Update test ADD counterRid = " + result.getRecord().field('@rid') ) ; `

counterRid is Linklist Field

Comment: Hi @BonieZat, I've tested your instruction about the `UPDATE...ADD` command with a `LINKLIST` field and it worked. Hope to have been helpful.